# Object deserialization

Tags: c#, generics, object, deserialization

for deserialization I use working method:

```
public static bool InvokeDeserializeMethod<T>(ref T o, string serializedObject)
        {
            Type[] typesParameters = new Type[]{typeof(string)};
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(o).GetMethod("Deserialize",typesParameters);
            object[] deserializeMethodParameters = new string [] {serializedObject};
            if (methodInfo != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    o = (T)methodInfo.Invoke(o, deserializeMethodParameters);
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Now I am making copy, paste functions, and I need to deserialize some serialized objects(strings)
I cant use this method, because I dont wanna send ref on some existing object, I new object to be created
It would be the best If I have a method like:

```
public static T InvokeDeserializeMethod<T>(string serializedObject)
```

Is there any way how to achieve it, return object of type T, without having existing object which I would send to method? (Every object I will use with this method contains serialize and deserialize method)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either one of the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d49ss92b.aspx) method overloads to create a instance of a known type, if you know it's constructor arguments, or [FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(Type t)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) if you don't want to invoke the types constructor on deserialization.